# jQuery plugin for grid like iOS home screen

Tags: ios, jquery-plugins

Requires the jQuery plugin as gridster/gridstack to create a drag-and-drop grid, but the elements must slide like app icons on iOS home screen. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say the elements must slide like app icons on the iOS home screen, what do you mean? I assume you can do whatever you're trying to do with gridstack?

Comment: @dweiss Elements must slide like "snake". There are some examples: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid or (list B) http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/ or https://www.bypeople.com/drag-drop-sortable-css-grid/